# field extension being algebraic is equivalent to every $K-$ algebra being an automorphism.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, ring-homomorphism

> For a field extension $L\vert K,$show that the  following statements
>   are equivalent :
>
> $(i)$$L\vert K$ is algebraic.
>
> $(ii)$ For every $E\in${$E:E$ is a field with $K\subset E\subset
>  L$},every $K-$ algebra homomorphism $\sigma:E\rightarrow E$ is an
>   automorphism.

Please provide some hint so that I can initiate this. I would be better if someone can provide a rough sketch of the above equivalence .

Comment: Here's a hint for the forward direction: Since $L/K$ is an algebraic extension, so is $E/K$ for any $K⊆E⊆L$. Now consider a $K$-homomorphism $σ:E→E$. Since $E$ is a field and $σ$ is non-zero (it fixes $K$), $\ker(σ)=0$. To show that it's surjective, consider an element $x∈E$. Since it's algebraic, let $f$ be it's minimal polynomial. Now note that $σ$ fixes the roots of $f$, i.e. conjugates of $x$. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: @stressedout:$ker(\sigma)=0\implies \sigma $ is injective;You've just shown that $\sigma $ is surjective;Since,$\sigma $ is considered as a homomorphism.Hence $\sigma $ is an automorphism.

Comment: @stressedout:Are  my  implications correct?

Comment: Well, yes but I haven't completely shown why $\sigma$ is surjective. I kind of left that part to you. The idea is that $\sigma$ fixes conjugates of $x$. How can you show from this that $x$ is in the image of $\sigma$?

Comment: @stressedout:We can define $\sigma :E\rightarrow E$ as $\sigma(x)=x$?

Comment: No. We don't define $\sigma$. We have no control over it. We have been given a $\sigma: E \to E$ and we want to show that it's bijective. Injectivity of $\sigma$ comes from the fact that $E$ is a field, so it has only two ideals $\{0\}$ and $E$ itself. Since $\sigma$ is not the zero homomorphism because it fixes $K$, $\ker{\sigma}$ cannot be $E$. So, $\ker{\sigma}=0$. So, $\sigma$ is injective. Also, $\sigma$ sends the roots of the minimal polynomial of an algebraic element to themselves. If $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are the roots of the minimal polynomial for $f$, $\sigma$ will permute them.

Comment: (continued) so, $\sigma(\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}) \subseteq \{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. Why does equality hold? Because $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a finite set and we have shown that $\sigma$ is injective. An injective function on a finite set is surjective. Hence, $\sigma(\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}) = \{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. In particular, since $x$ is in $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$, we have shown that $x$ is in the image of $\sigma$. This proves that $\sigma$ is surjective.

Comment: @stressedout:thanks a lot!!

Comment: @stressedout:What about the converse part?

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly speaking, I have taught about the converse, but I don't know how to solve it yet. I tried to assume that $L/K$ had a transcendental element and then reach a contradiction, without success. So, I think you should wait for someone with a better knowledge in algebra to answer the converse part.

Comment: @stressedout:No problem,lets think about it...

Comment: Your choice of tags suggests that $E$ is finite. Then an injective mapping from $E$ to itself is automatically bijective. A homomorphism of rings is injective if and only if the kernel is the zero ideal. But that's the only ideal a field has (given that $1$ is not in the kernel)?